# How to change the pod if I have to fix something while using cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Very new to Cocoapods. I am wondering how to change my dependencies properly for my project supporting cocoapods.

Let say I have a project which using `AFNetworking`. I want to change some file of the standard library of `AFNetworking` and use them into my project. And anytime after command line `pod install`, I have to go to the standard `AFNetworking` library and fix something manually.

I am sure I am not understanding well what cocoapods would help if I need to change some source file of a dependency. Please help me to become better.

Thanks.

Comment: if u change some dependency in Headerfile, then  don't use pods , download and add it manually.

Comment: Yes, it is the normal way. I just want to know could the pod point to my forked git (which had changed) directly, so that I can use it in my podfile?

Comment: assume that u change something in pod file , then u add something like "xxx" in pods , then u add the command "pod install", the updated dependency replace the old one.

Comment: Yes, I got you. But the updated is official. And I only want to change what I need to proper for my project, likes adjusting fonts, text. etc.

Comment: Can you give some example what you are trying to modify? In such situations, try subclassing from AFNetworking class and apply your changes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fork [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to your repositories, and release a new version with your code (for example: with tag "v2.5.1"). then you can pod AFNetworking like this:

`pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/yourgithub/AFNetworking.git', :tag => 'v2.5.1'`

Once you want to pull new codes from AFNetworking, just rebase in your branch and release a new version.

Answer (score 1):

See [the official documentation](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#from-a-podspec-in-the-root-of-a-library-repo) in CocoaPods Guides that explains how to do this.